# Severe Compatibility mode issue with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, mode

All programs on my laptop somehow and out of no where changed it's compatibility mode settings even windows programs like Microsoft photo viewer! They all are changed! Some say windows vista some say XP or 98 I don't know but I didn't do anything that I'm aware of to have this happen. I can't even view photos anymore because of this and I can't change it manually because their all greyed out (i.e "Microsoft-like" programs)

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility settings are found in the registry, here

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

You can start regedit or regedt32 (search for it in the start menu) and check if all your applications are present here. You can then delete a few, to see if they start working again.

Your problem might be caused by some tool or application which you are using (or even by malware), so this fix is only treating the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: Didn't help at all, that only shows the programs i have changed personally.